# Pass only specific variables to a shiny app when building a package

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, workspace, scoping

I'm building a package which includes my shiny app.

To do this, I build a wrapper around my "shiny::runApp" call, but unfortunatly the shiny app uses the global workspace variables.
I want the wraper function to use the variables i give to the function (and error if not supplemented) and use them for shiny. Here for example, it need x,y and z (which has a default value):

```
Shiny_wrapper <- function(x,y,z=TRUE){
    shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("shinyApp", package = "WebFlood"))
}
```

I worked around it by assigning the variables to the global workspace, but I don't think this is the right approach:

```
Shiny_wrapper <- function(x,y,z=TRUE){
    x<<-x
    y<<-y
    z<<-z
    shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("shinyApp", package = "WebFlood"))
}
```

How do I get my shiny to use the variables I pass to the wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an environment in your package, and use it to pass some variables.

```
PKGENVIR <- new.env(parent=emptyenv()) 

#' @export
Shiny_wrapper <- function(x,y,z=TRUE){
    PKGENVIR$x <- x
    PKGENVIR$y <- y
    PKGENVIR$z <- z
    shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("shinyApp", package = "WebFlood"))
}
```

And then in the shiny app (in `global.R` or `server.R`):

```
x <- WebFlood:::PKGENVIR$x
```

Comment: This looks good, but I also need it in the UI, since it determines some of the variables there. Any chance to use this for the UI too?

Comment: @Squeezie If you use `global.R` I think the variables are available in the UI. No?

Comment: Works flawless. Thank you!